# Invalid file when uploading form in Django with a file field

Tags: python, django

I am new Django and am creating a social network website to get my hands on it. I have made a form for uploading profile picture and successfully rendered in my template but when I am uploading it I am getting an error named **profile_pic**. Please help me out with this.

> **views.py** - This is the processing that I am doing. I get here an invalid form error and the line **return HttpResponse(profilePicForm.errors)** returns **profile_pic** as response.

```
if request.method == "POST":
        profilePicForm = ProfilePicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if profilePicForm.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse("<h1>Valid</h1>")
            profilePic = ProfilePictures()
            query = UserInfo.objects.filter(id=id)
            for user in query:
                profilePic.user = user
                break
            profilePic.profile_pic = profilePicForm.cleaned_data['profile_pic']
            profilePic.save()
            return redirect('newsfeed:profile')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(profilePicForm.errors)
```

> **forms.py** - The form class

```
class ProfilePicForm(forms.Form):
    profile_pic = forms.FileField()
```

> **profile.html** - This is how I am rendering it.

```
<form action="{% url 'newsfeed:uploadProfilePic' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ profilePicForm.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: This does not provide any direct solution to your problem but just to let you know there is an `ImageField` in Django that you can use! Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common practice to render same template if form is not valid, to see error messages on the web page, so instead of `return HttpResponse(profilePicForm.errors)` you shoud do something like this:

```
if profilePicForm.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse("<h1>Valid</h1>")
        profilePic = ProfilePictures()
        query = UserInfo.objects.filter(id=id)
        for user in query:
            profilePic.user = user
            break
        profilePic.profile_pic = profilePicForm.cleaned_data['profile_pic']
        profilePic.save()
        return redirect('newsfeed:profile')
    else:
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'profilePicForm': profilePicForm})
```

Also for file uploading you should add to the form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`:

```
<form action="{% url 'newsfeed:uploadProfilePic' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ profilePicForm.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: With print(profilePicForm.errors) I am getting - <ul class="errorlist"><li>profile_pic<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: @kodeturtle looks like you missed `enctype="multipart/form-data"` check updates.

Comment: Oyes, it worked. That was a very silly mistake from my side. Thank You!